# How to find the domain and range of an implicit function?

Tags: functions

For example, we have this curve:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

Is there a function in *Mathematica* for finding out that the ranges for $x$ and $y$ are both $[-1, 1]$?

What about implicit functions of more than $2$ variables? e.g.

$$x^2 + y^2 + z = 1$$

Comment: Maybe `Reduce[Exists[{x}, x^2 + y^2 == 1 ], Reals]` : -1<=y<=1

Comment: Great! Is there any way for applying this result to the plotting functions?

Comment: For applying the result to plotting functions, it would be hard to find a solution that is a little bit generic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe :

```
Reduce[Exists[{x}, x^2 + y^2 == 1 ], Reals]
```

> -1<=y<=1

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if this will work for you, but... There is a cool blog by [**Roman Osipov**](http://community.wolfram.com/web/raosipov) in Russian (use Google Translate to translate):

[**Study of arbitrary functions by methods of mathematical analysis in the system Mathematica**](http://allmathematica.blogspot.com/2013/06/Issledovanie-funkcii-metodami-matematicheskogo-analiza-v-Mathematica.html)

I will give 2 functions from there (see the blog for more tricks). The domain of the function

```
DefinitionDomain[expr_, variable_: x] := 
 If[Head[#] === List, #, 
    List[#]] &@(Reduce[Element[expr, Reals] && Denominator[expr] != 0,
      variable, Reals] /. Or -> List)
```

The range of the function

```
RangeValues[expr_, variable_: x] := 
 Reduce[Or @@ 
   Cases[FullForm@
     Flatten[Reduce[y == expr, variable, Reals] /. And | Or -> List], 
    Inequality[___, y, ___] | LessEqual[_, y, _] | Less[_, y, _] | 
     y <= _ | y >= _ | y > _ | y < _ | y == _, Infinity], y, Reals]
```

Now, this may not be what you need, but - express explicitly what is the function and what is the argument:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[1 - x^2]
```

Then

```
DefinitionDomain[f[x], x]
```

> {-1 <= x <= 1}

and

```
RangeValues[f[x], x]
```

> 0 <= y <= 1

Comment: Perhalf it is wrong with the function f[x_] := (x^2 + x + 1) (x^2 + x + 2)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe what you want is [`CylindricalDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html):

```
CylindricalDecomposition[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, y}]
```

> $-1<x<1\land -\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: This is limited to polynomial equations.

Comment: All your examples are polynomial equations.

Comment: :), yeah, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

In version 10,

```
RegionBounds@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}]

(* ==> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}} *)

FunctionRange[{y, x^2 + y^2 < 1}, x, y]

(* ==> -1 < y < 1 *)
```